# Multiple counts in a single query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query where I have to count multiple fields

```
select 
distinct(custsegment),
(select count(distinct clid) from call_log where enteredon = '16-JUL-13') as     UniqCalls,
(select count(disconnectflag) from call_log where disconnectflag='IVR' and enteredon =     '16-JUL-13') as IvrCalls,
(select count(callerid) from call_log where enteredon = '16-JUL-13') as TotalCalls
from call_log
where enteredon = '16-JUL-13'
```

Output is

```
CUSTSEGMENT  UNIQCALLS   IVRCALLS TOTALCALLS
------------ ---------- ---------- ----------
PRIORITY             12          6         12 
NORMAL               12          6         12
```

But problem appears like I'm getting same values for PRIORITY and NORMAL CUSTSEGMENT, also I'm not sure whether this is the right way of counting it. Please suggest.

Comment: Your positioning of the keyword `distinct` suggests that you think that it applies to `custsegment` only, but this is not the case. It just unduplicates the records in your resultset, comparing all columns.

Comment: @GolezTrol : Is this the right way of doing it or any other approaches are there? I usually work with MSSQL, going through difficult time on Oracle...

Comment: Same applies to MSSQL or any database. The query is not wrong per se, but your indentation and the use of parentheses show that you misunderstand the `distinct` keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant to `group by` custsegment. This also makes your query a bit simpler, because you don't need the subselects.

```
select 
  custsegment,
  count(distinct clid) as UniqCalls,
  count(case when disconnectflag = 'IVR' then 1 else null end) as IvrCalls,
  -- sum(case when disconnectflag = 'IVR' then 1 else 0 end) as IvrCalls,
  count('x') as TotalCalls
from call_log
where enteredon = '16-JUL-13'
group by
  custsegment
```

To count the IvrCalls, you can do it in a couple of ways. `Count` counts all non-null values, so you can use a case for that (and you can even leave out `else null`). Or you can use `sum` which is also commonly used.

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the problem, since the subqueries are not related to the main query.

Comment: this should do the trick if every subquery had a where clause to match `custsegment` with the main query table.

Comment: @GoatCO -  I fixed the query. The subselects are actually not needed at all, I think.

Comment: @JafarKofahi I know. I was in the process of fixing that already. I eliminated the subselects completely.

Comment: This worked and I believe this is the right way of doing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your three sub-queries

```
select count(distinct clid) from call_log where enteredon = '16-JUL-13')
select count(disconnectflag) from call_log where disconnectflag='IVR' and enteredon =     '16-JUL-13'
select count(callerid) from call_log where enteredon = '16-JUL-13')
```

Are executed exactly as they written, for every row in the result set. That is why you are seeing the same values repeated.

Since you want to group over multiple fields, which do not have mutually exclusive results, I'd say (and this may not be the best way of doing it) group for each of the items you are interested in, and then combine your results.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
Select 
c.custsegment,
count(distinct clid) as     UniqCalls,
count(callerid) as TotalCalls
from call_log c 
inner join
(select count(disconnectflag) as IvrCalls, custsegment 
from call_log where disconnectflag='IVR' and enteredon = '16-JUL-13' group by custsegment) t

on c.custsegment=t.custsegment

where enteredon = '16-JUL-13'
group by c.custsegment
```

Comment: How is IvrCalls being displayed in the final query? I only see it referenced in the sub-query, but never referenced in the outer query.